# docker bind one port，but bind other port, service access failed

Tags: docker

firstly, docker run sevice bind ports 8080,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF2vU.png)

docker run -d --name myjenkins -p 8080:8080 
-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
docker-jenk

localhost:8080 could access

Then: dicker stop and rm

Thirdly： docker run the same sevice bind ports 8081,
docker run -d --name myjenkins -p 8081:8081 
-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
docker-jenk

localhost:8081 couldn't access

why???

Comment: English please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind ports, the syntax is `-p <host port>:<container port>`. Your container listens on port 8080 and that doesn't change. You can change what host port you map to.

If you want to map to port 8081, you should do `-p 8081:8080`. Then you should be able to access it on localhost:8081.